# PHP array post data

Tags: php, arrays, post

Form:
    $headerValues=array();

```
$headerValues[1][2]="Test";
... 
....
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ArrayData\" value=\"$headerValues\"/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />";
```

How do I read headerValues on FORM POST , I see as ARRAY when I use this code

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key) { 
   $$key = $_POST[$key]; 
   print "$key is ${$key}<br />";
   print_r(${$key}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$headerValues=htmlspecialchars(serialize(array('blah','test')));
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ArrayData\" value=\"$headerValues\"/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />";
```

to get

```
$value = unserialize($_POST['ArrayData']);
```

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're *outputting* the string "ARRAY" as the value of your field.  This is what happens when you cast an array to a string in PHP. Check the HTML source next time you have similar problems, it's a pretty crucial step in debugging HTML.

Use this instead:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ArrayData\" value=\"", implode(' ', $headerValues), '"/>';
```

The way you handle the input is also needlessly complex, this would suffice:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
  echo "$key is $value<br />";
```

Comment: Haha. I like how out of 5 answers you have the only one that's anywhere near the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write out multiple `<input name="ArrayData[]">` elements, one for each value. The empty square brackets signify to PHP that it should store each of these values in an array when the form is submitted.

```
$headerValues=array('blah','test');

for ($headerValues as $value) {
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ArrayData[]\" value=\"$value\"/>";
}
```

Then `$_POST['ArrayData']` will be an array you can loop over:

```
foreach ($_POST['ArrayData'] as $i => $value) {
    echo "ArrayData[$i] is $value<br />";
}
```