# Pass array from one page to another

Tags: php

I have an array containing some values, say

```
arr['one'] = "one value here";
arr['two'] = "second value here";
arr['three'] = "third value here";
```

I this values are in the page home.php and at the end of the page it is redirected to page detail.php
Now i want to pass this array from page home.php to detail.php when direct occur.

In how many ways I can send this value using post and get method. Also if possible show me how to receive and print those values in detail.php page.

An example of each type is much appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't use sessions here

Comment: Sessions shall be use for application wide needed information. Using it to move info from one page to another is dumb and may lead to problems

Comment: what is the problem with sessions @Alexander

Comment: @Alexander: I disagree, session is a perfect way to keep data between multiple pages. Especially when you want to redirect to a script to avoid reposting data or when you want to redirect to an error page and keep the error message somewhere (out of the URL data)

Comment: @Alexander is right. Sessions are as avoidable as possible, and HTTP should remain stateless as long as live things like push notifications / sockets are not involved [see REST principles]. If you just want to flash messages it's ok then, but I would have tackled the problem the async way better.

Comment: Having said that, there are cases when it is useful and necessary [making use of sessions.] Notwithstanding, OP's question doesn't seem to be one of those or it is not deeply explained. Anyways, [in PHP] there's no accounting for taste

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the session to store the array from one page to another:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['array_to_save'] = $arr;
```

More info on the sessions : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

If you don't want to use session you can do something like this in your first page

```
$serialized =htmlspecialchars(serialize($arr));
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ArrayData\" value=\"$serialized\"/>";
```

and in the other one you retrieve the array data like this :

```
$value = unserialize($_POST['ArrayData']);
```

Solution found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638962/1606729

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to use sessions, you can just include the page in the other file.

**file1.php**

```
<php
    $arr = array();
    $arr['one'] = "one value here";
    $arr['two'] = "second value here";
    $arr['three'] = "third value here";
?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php

    include "file1.php";

    print_r($arr);
?>
```

If the array is dynamically created and you want to pass it through GET or POST you should form the URL on the server side and redirect the user to the HTTP URL page instead of the php file.

So something like:

**file1.php**

```
<php
    $arr = array();
    $arr['one'] = "one value here";
    $arr['two'] = "second value here";
    $arr['three'] = "third value here";

    $redirect = "http://yoursite.com/file2.php?".http_build_query($arr);
    header( "Location: $redirect" );

?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php

    $params = $_GET;

    print_r($params['one']);
    print_r($params['two']);
    print_r($params['three']);
?>
```

Comment: I think his array is dynamically constructed/filled

Comment: Ah! I see. yeah. He needs to use sessions. If not that, do the redirect through the first page internally.

Comment: I know this was posted a long time ago but this really helped me! Thank you @Kartik

Answer (score 2):

home.php file

```
session_start();
if(!empty($arr)){
    $_SESSION['value'] = $arr;
     redirect_to("../detail.php");
}
```

detail.php

```
session_start();                    
if(isset($_SESSION['value'])){                           
    foreach ($_SESSION['value'] as $arr) {
        echo $arr . "<br />";
        unset($_SESSION['value']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values by query parameters, too.

```
header('Location: detail.php?' . http_build_query($arr, null, '&'));
```

And you can get the array in the detail.php like this:

```
// your values are in the $_GET array
echo $_GET['one'];  // echoes "one value here" by your example
```

Be aware that if you pass values by GET or POST (hidden input field), they can be changed by the user easily.