# How to send the exact same table to the next page in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a multiple choice question exam and I have created the following code to fetch an array of questions from my database and place it in a table according to users specifications:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
// I did not include the $connx and $sqlx to make the code shorter for here 
$resultx = $connx->query($sqlx);
$qcounter = 1;
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    echo '<tr><td>Question '.$qcounter.'<br/></td></tr>';
    $qcounter++;
    //output a row here
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['Question'])."</td></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '" value="A" id="question-1-answers-A"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">A)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerA']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '" value="B" id="question-1-answers-B"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">B)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerB']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '" value="C" id="question-1-answers-C"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerC']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="question-id" id="question-id" value='.($row['id']).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="question_bar_code" id="question_bar_code" value='.($row['CorrectAnswer']).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><br/></td></tr>';

echo "</table>";
?>
<input class="hvr-fade1" type="submit" value="Finish">
</form>
```

Now everything is fine with this page, exam is shown as wanted but I would like to send the table data to analyze on the next page which is result.php

I would like the exam same table data to go the next page and be placed in the exact same place. How would I achieve that?

I tried this
[Pass array from one page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811385/pass-array-from-one-page-to-another)
but with a very little success.

My apologies that I don't mean anyone to write the syntax for me. any answer is appreciated.

Thanks,
oliver

Comment: are you taking about you want to analyze data in result.php page?

Comment: I am going to analyze it by showing the score and everything which I know how to do so but I want the table data that is created here to be shown on the next page, that means same questions and choices to appear on the next page after submit.

Comment: well, you have a form and some data input fields. When the user submits the form, these will be available as the variables in the `$_POST` array in result.php. They will be idenfitable by the "name" attribute of each input. So `$_POST["q1"]` will be the value the user entered for question 1. So you can do whatever you like with them - process them, save them, or output them to the page again.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I am working on it, with POST since the qcounter is generating the number I feel it might be problematic, I'm using print_r to send the result to the next page now and I will see the result

Comment: I think you shouldn't run `$qcounter++;` until the last line of your while loop. Otherwise the first radio buttons will be q2, not q1. Is that causing you an issue?

Comment: @ADyson you are right actually about the '$qcounter++;' but my problem is that with POST only the selected radio button, the question id and the question_bar_code are POSTed, the rest are not inputs and not posted. I kinda want the same table generated here to go to the next page

Comment: well, in the first place you get all the questions and options from the database, right? So just retrieve that again. The question IDs will be in the POST variables because you have put it in the hidden field in the form, so you will know which question to retrieve. All you have to add in are the answers, which are in the POST variables. You might have to change `name="question-id"` to `name="question-id[]"` to get an array of all the question IDs into the post.

Comment: It can be a good solution, I'm going to try that!

Comment: Thanks, ultimately used the POST to get the data to be shown n result.php